# Extracting values ​from the database by enum

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I am extracting data from the database in the controller, through the model, but in the final results I show the data (int) instead of the values ​​under these numbers from enuma

I'm stuck at this point and I don't know how to do it

Model:

```
public partial class Akceptation_v_Model
{
   public EnumKindOfSomethink KindOfSomethink{ get; set; }
}

public enum EnumKindOfSomethink
{
    UoP = 1,
    B2B = 2,
    UZ = 3
}
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSubordinates(DataSourceLoadOptions loadOptions)
{

    var Get = _ecpContext.Akceptation_v
                            .Select(i => new
                            {
                                i.KindOfSomethink
                            });

    return Json(await DataSourceLoader.LoadAsync(Get , loadOptions));
}
```

Now: Result in table: 1 or 2 or 3

I would like it to look like this:: UoP or B2B or UZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with updating `i.KindOfSomethink` to `KindOfSomethink = i.KindOfSomethink.ToString()`.

---

Your `Select` will look like below if you want result like `[{ KindOfSomethink = "UoP" }, { KindOfSomethink = "B2B" }]` then

```
.Select(i => new
{
   KindOfSomethink = i.KindOfSomethink.ToString()
});
```

---

Your `Select` will look like below if you want result like `["UoP", "B2B"]` then

```
.Select(i => i.KindOfSomethink.ToString());
```

Comment: Error CS0746 Invalid anonymous type member declarator